# Excel Nested IF is not being evaluated as a formula. The output of the cell is the actual Formula itself

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

So I have a table and in one of the table columns I have the following

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("JugA",[@[Original Wonderware Tag Name]])),"0",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("JugB",[@[Original Wonderware Tag Name]])),"1",""))`

The output should be a string it should be "0","1","" (the last one just being a blank cell.

The problem is that the displayed output of the cell is the formula itself. it doesn't even give me an error message.

EIA:

I have checked "Show Formulas" is off, that is not the issue

Comment: Your cell's format might be on 'text'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was because the cell was formatted at "Text" instead of "General" or some other format